# active admin not override controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I'm using active admin and want to customize update action. But after submit form control is

not coming in update action.

My code is below.

```
     ActiveAdmin.register Job do

          form :partial => 'jobs/form'

          controller do

          def update
            update! do |format|
              binding.pry
              format.html
            end
          end
        end  
      end
```

Any help??

Thanks

Comment: The default HTTP response for a successful `update` action is a redirect, which may be the issue. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: try putting that binding.pry as the first statement in your action and check if the code enters there.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
controller do
    def create
      @foo = Foo.new(permitted_params['some_params'])
        if @foo.save
          binding.pry
          puts 'foo'
          redirect_to admin_foo_path(@foo)
        end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its works for me

```
def update
  super do |format|
    binding.pry
    redirect_to collection_url
  end
end
```